Using join with hierarchy query
I'm trying to query as below but not getting result as expected
Select * from a where a.a='G'
Join lateral
Select * from b start with b.col1= a.col1 connect by prior b.col2=b.col2
Join
Select * from c where c.q='L' and c.col1=a.col1

Is this possible without getting duplicates?
Tried this as well
Select * from a where a.a='G'
Join lateral
Select * from b start with b.col1= a.col1 connect by prior b.col2=b.col2
Union all
Select * from c where c.q='L' and c.col1=a.col1

